# how to shrink an image in size in android layout?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, layout, imageview

I have an image that I want to display in android layout

but I want to make it proportionally smaller than its original size.

How can I do this?

if I specify some width and height it crops the image instead of shrinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scaleType attribute to define the scaling of the ImageView, e.g. :

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the image to 80% size using the below code sample.

```
int srcWidth = srcBitmap.getWidth();
int srcHeight = srcBitmap.getHeight();
int dstWidth = (int)(srcWidth*0.8f);
int dstHeight = (int)(srcHeight*0.8f);
Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
```

Change the multiple value based on the % you need to scale.

Also, refer to this link for more options.
[Scaling bitmap to 80 percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391626/scaling-bitmap-to-80-percent)