# Scaling and translating a bitmap in android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, scaling

I am trying to sale a bitmap and translating it at each step.

If we look at the following code, I am drawing an image, translating and scaling it and then performing the same operations in reverse so as to get the original configuration back. But after applying the operations, I do get the original scaled image (scale factor 1) but the image is translated t a different position.

Could you please point out the correct method do so ? (In the example above, how do I reach the original configuration? )

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        scale = (float)screenWidth/201.0f;
        matrix.setTranslate(-40, -40);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, matrix, paint);

        //back to original
        canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
        matrix.setScale(1.0f/scale, 1.0f/scale);
        matrix.setTranslate(40,40);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, matrix, paint);

    }
```

Comment: Refer following link it will help you [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722359/scale-rotate-bitmap-using-matrix-in-android

Comment: `Matrix.setXXX` will do reset matrix first , and set value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use the `Canvas` methods for scaling and translating, that way you can then take advantage of the `save()` and `restore()` APIs to do what you need. For example:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //Save the current state of the canvas
    canvas.save();

    scale = (float) screenWidth / 201.0f;

    canvas.translate(-40, -40);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, 0, 0, paint);

    //Restore back to the state it was when last saved
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitMap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem but any pointers as to why my code is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your original code might be because of the way scale and translate use the point around which you scale/translate. IF you specify the correct pivot points in between/for the operations, things will be ok.