# drawBitmap: How can you set coordinates and use a matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, draw

I've been [looking at the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) and the only `drawBitmap()` that allows a `Matrix` as parameter doesn't take any kind of screen coordinates by parameter.

I'm using the following code to draw my bitmap with a matrix rotation:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(rotation,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Which of course draws my bitmap at `0,0`. How can I set the position and use the matrix?

Ideally I'd like to use the destination Rect:

```
this.destRect = new Rect(   
                    x - spriteWidth / 2,
                    y - spriteHeight / 2,
                    x + spriteWidth / 2,
                    y + spriteHeight /2
);
```

Edit:

Following suggestin in comment I tried this:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setTranslate(x, y);
    matrix.setRotate(rotation,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

but to no avail. Bitmap is still drawn at `0,0`

Edit2:

Here's the trick to rotate an image on itself using a matrix and then place it at `x,y`:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2); // Centers image
    matrix.postRotate(rotation);
    matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: maybe setTranslate http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setTranslate(float, float)

Comment: @JRowan Thanks for the answer! I gave it a try but couldn't get it to work (see update).

Comment: check this one out, you can translate the canvas then restore it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709360/scaling-and-translating-a-bitmap-in-android

Comment: @JRowan thanks for the link, the trick is to `postTranslate` and center the image on itself, then `postRotate` then `postTranslate` the image to the desired coords (see update)