# How to scale Bitmap drawn on the Canvas while saving rotation and translation specified with Matrix

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, matrix-multiplication

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrfQ7.png)

Hi everyone. I am new to Image manipulation in android using matrix. I am working on an app which displays Bitmap #1 on the screen of the device.

Bitmap #1 is really big, about 2592 X 1456, but scaled down to fit the screen size of the device for displaying purposes only.

Then I have drawn the lips Bitmap (#2) on Bitmap #1 Canvas, using matrix (with rotate, scale, translation), as image above is showing.

Precisely what I want to achieve is to save a copy of the final Bitmap, scaled backwards to the original size (2592 x 1456).

I tried to achieve it by scaling Bitmap #1 matrix.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    // adjust the matrix to the original image size
    // new matrix big
    Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(); 
    // copy matrix from small matrix
    newMatrix = matrix; 
    RectF src = new RectF(0,0,backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
    RectF dst = new RectF(0,0, origBackground.getWidth(), origBackground.getHeight());
    newMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, newMatrix, paint);
```

My problem is that in the resulting Bitmap #1, lips Bitmap (#2) is being placed at the x=0 and y=0 and not at the required coordinates, missing specified rotation.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#scaling

Comment: Hi @xAF. This is drawn on canvas. I am not using any widget that automatically adjust to screen. I am using matrix to do it.

Comment: Please check out my proposed edit (hope I understood your question well)

Answer (score 0):

For scaling purposes the better option is to use Canvas own `save()` and `restore()` methods.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709419/5908572).

For your purpose use [`translate(x,y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw at specific coordinates and [`rotate(deg,x,y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw at specific rotation angle pinned at specific coordinates.

Hope this would help solve your issues.

Comment: Hi @xAF that  is correct but I want it to be in Matrix solution. So I converted your answer in a matrix solution. Above is my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of trying. I finally got the answer. Below is the source code that I've been using. Thanks to @xAF.

Cheers,

```
public Bitmap saveBitmap()
   {
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(bm);
    // draw the background photo with its original size
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null);

    // put the lips and adjust the matrix to the original image size
    Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(); // new big matrix
    // copy the screen small matrix (with rotate, scale, translation)
    newMatrix.set(matrix);
    float scaleWidth = ((float) bitmap1.getWidth()) / bitmap2.getWidth();
    float scaleHeight = ((float) bitmap1.getHeight()) / bitmap2.getHeight();

    newMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 0, 0);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmapLips, newMatrix, paint);

    return bm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do that thanks to setRectToRect function like that :

```
 val matrix = Matrix().apply {
            matrix.setRectToRect(
                RectF(0f, 0f, icon.getWidth().toFloat(), icon.getHeight().toFloat()),
                RectF(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f),
                Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER
            )
            matrix.postTranslate(centerX - 50f, centerX - 50f)
        } 
 canvas.drawBitmap(
            icon,
            matrix,
            Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.DITHER_FLAG or Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG)
        )
```

here i resize my bitmap with width = 100f and height = 100f
Then i still can translate it or rotate it