# card game hand formation using imageviews in android

Tags: android

I have developed a four player spades-like card game.I Use imageviews for displaying players' hands. I wanna show each player's hand in an arc(like in real life). I think I should use rotation and translation. how should I do that? Do you know any tutorials that does that?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be to do the following:

**Positioning**
To create the arc, I would go and use a `FrameLayout` holding the `ImageViews`. This has the advantage that you can easily overlay the Views. I would set the position by using the center. This way, you could easily calculate the positions by using a function like `y = - (x*scale)^2 + offset`. Here is an example of what you could use: [Click](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%28x/2%29%5E2%2b0.2). But you need to play around with the values a little bit to get a function that looks good for you. Also, the y-axis should then be in the middle of the screen (or you can modify the input of the method by subtracting screenwidth/2 or sth like that). To actually define the position, you then need to modify the margin of the `ImageView`

**Rotation**
Since every card should have a different rotation, I would define a maximum angle and a minimum angle. (Those might be between 15° and 30° == pi/12 and pi/6)
To find out more about rotation itself, google will probably help. I immediately:
[Scale & rotate Bitmap using Matrix in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722359/scale-rotate-bitmap-using-matrix-in-android)
[Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)

**Z-Order**
To handle the z-order in the `FrameLayout`, you can use [ViewGroup.bringChildToFront(View child)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront%28android.view.View%29) that `FrameLayout`inherits from `ViewGroup`. I would store the cards in an array and iterate over it, calling `bringChildToFront`on every `ImageView`.

This definitely only is a starting point, but having more concrete problems, you will receive more concrete answers to your question!